# Perform Action after duration if buttonIndex of alertView is not clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to display a temporary alert for about 2 seconds to give the user a chance to cancel an action. If the user clicks the cancel button, the subsequent method would not be called. However, if the user does not press cancel, then the subsequent method would be called. Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
-(void) buttonPress {

    //alert with message and cancel button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"2 seconds to cancel" 
    message:@"Push Cancel to stop" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];
    return;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView.tag == 1) {

        //action cancelled
    }
    else {

        //action not cancelled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to dismiss alert after 2 seconds :

```
-(void) buttonPress {

    //alert with message and cancel button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"2 seconds to cancel" 
    message:@"Push Cancel to stop" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];

    // Create the perform selector method with alert view object and time-period
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:alert afterDelay:2];
    return;
}


// Dismiss the alert view after time-Period     
-(void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView.tag == 1) {

        //action cancelled
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) object:alertView];
    }
    else {

        //action not cancelled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one method which will be called after 2 seconds and  dismiss the alertview and perform the task which you want to do.

You can call that method as follows -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: When the cancel button is pressed you cancel the perform selector using: `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourTarget selector:aSelector object: anArgument];`

Comment: @BhaveshNai - No. 2 means 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Set an NSTimer with the delay you want (2 secs).  In the timer's delegate, call UIAlertView's delegate with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Start an `NSTimer` when you show the alert (non repeating) and cancel it in the delegate callback. If the timer fires, dismiss the alert and call your subsequent task.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(popViewAfterMessage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) popViewAfterMessage {
    // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is logic..

1. A temporary alert for about 2 seconds to give the user a chance to cancel an action.

   > > Set a flag variable to get indication weather to continue or not.
2. If the user clicks the cancel button, the subsequent method would not be called.

   > > Start timer for 2 seconds as soon as UIAlertview comes in front of user and set flag false.
3. However, if the user does not press cancel, then the subsequent method would be called.

   > > Hide UIAlertview, stop 2 second timer & flag value will be true and call your subsequent method to continue with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(FunctionName) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
-(Void)YourFunctionName
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will even run if your app goes in background after alert view in shown.

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

   NSTimer* currentTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(YourMethodName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Enjoy!!....

Answer (score -1):

Use this function:

```
- (void)hideAllAlerts {

    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
        if ([subviews count] > 0)
            if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
                [(UIAlertView *)[subviews objectAtIndex:0] dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)[subviews objectAtIndex:0] cancelButtonIndex] animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Change Your Code:

```
-(void) buttonPress {

    //alert with message and cancel button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"2 seconds to cancel" 
    message:@"Push Cancel to stop" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideAllAlerts) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    return;
}
```

Comment: first one is return statement in first line. and others

Comment: And the second is [subviews objectAtIndex:0] may not be an UIAlertView you should use for() cycle instead of if()

Comment: I have implemented this code in my app and it worked for every scenerios. It is tested

Comment: This is just because the alert is laying on the top of view hierarchy. But this is the only case it will work fine. The all tricky bugs started from "I'm definitely sure, this var can't be more than X" someday under some circumstances it WILL BE more than x. So, DO NOT HARDCODE!

Answer (score -1):

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(sendMail) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```